# Find unused functions in unit

Tags: java, netbeans

I have very complicated class code and I have feeling that half of it's functions are unused.
Is it possible to find unused functions in selected unit in NetBeans java project? Should I use some plugins for this purpose?

Comment: Have a look at Sonarqube, it provides code coverage.

Answer (score 0):

For netbeans there is **[DEAD CODE DETECTOR](https://java.net/projects/dcd)**

https://java.net/projects/dcd

OR as suggested by @Berger

Try Open source Quality Managemet Platform **[Sonarqube](http://www.sonarqube.org)**

http://www.sonarqube.org